# How to use Partials in ASP MVC when used with Javascript to call a Controller Action?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, partials

new kid on the block w/ASP MVC ... tryna get an Edit form going in a JavaScript dialog box.

my current plan of action:

- Main view has the edit button which onClick grabs the record_id, and makes an ajax call to my Controller-Action passing the record_id as the param.
- In the same view, I am using a partial "_EditApp" which has the tabs/dialog related code.
- In the same onClick, I am loading up the tabs that I specify in _EditApp.

JS ..

```
$('.btn_edit_app').click(function () {

    var app_to_edit = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Application/editApp',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        data: { app_id: app_to_edit},
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (result) {},
    });
    $('#edit_tabs').tabs({ active: 0 });
    $('#edit_dialog').dialog({ width: 700, height: 400 });
});
```

my Controller/Action

```
public ActionResult editApp(int app_id)
        {       
            AppDBServer ads = new AppDBServer();
            ads = findADS(app_id);
            return View("_EditApplication", ads); 
        }
```

the problem ...

simply, I want to retrieve the record and populate the tabs and dialog box with the retrieved data fields. Hence passing the model to the EditApplication Partial.

The issue is I am using the same partial in my main view that I am in the controller action and not sure how to go about this ... Ideas, or even a newer approach to this would be A-OK.

Also, I aiming to have data retrieval handled by the Controller / Action.

Thank you, SOF fam!

Answer (score 0):

I only wanted to comment but I can't since I have less than 50 reputation. Anyways, if I understand correctly you want to pull up some tabs after a an action call. I've had to something like this before. Here was my solution:

onclick of the button or row with the ID call an ActionResult.

Or use an Ajax Form:
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetTabs", "ControllerHere", new AjaxOptions() { LoadingElementId = "loading", UpdateTargetId = "targetdiv", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET" }))
{
@Html.Hidden("id", id)
....
Submit
}

Return a PartialView i.e. "_Tabs" and pass the model (id in this case).

```
`
public ActionResult GetTabs(string id)
{
....
//pass id or get model and pass model
return PartialView("_Tabs", id); 
}
`
```

Within the _Tabs.cshtml call Html.RenderAction for each tab. 
(I had set up tabs using bootstrap)
Html.RenderAction takes an action method name and you can pass parameters.

```
`@{Html.RenderAction("GetTab1",new {id = @id}) }

@{Html.RenderAction("GetTab2",new {id = @id}) }`
```

..etc

Each Action will return a partial view...
    
    `public ActionResult GetTab1(string id)
    {
     //get data 
     model = id lookup 
     return PartialView("_Tab1", model);
    }`

...etc

So now we have the _Tabs partial view rendering its own partial views each that can have their very own model.

And when the _Tabs partial is done rendering it will return the HTML to the target div on the main page and have the x number of tabs you have created in the _Tabs.cshtml.

I also was able to keep the current active tab selected with the following script:

```js
<script>
    $('#navtab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });

    // store the currently selected tab in the hash value
    $("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
        var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
        window.location.hash = id;
    });

    // on load of the page: switch to the currently selected tab
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('#navtab a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');
</script>
```